# how do we setup s3cmd on windows7

Tags: python, rake, windows-7-x64, s3cmd

I have successfully installed s3cmd(http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) on a windows 7 machine. I first installed python 2.7
added python to my path
then ran python setup.py install
I also added the python\scripts folder to my path but I can't run s3cmd from the dos prompt by simply running s3cmd but I can run the command if I use the full path like this

```
> python c:\Python27\Scripts\s3cmd
```

My issue is that I use ruby rake to automate some tasks and it needs to run on both windows & mac, is there a way I could simply run s3cmd like I would on linux or a mac?

Thanks!!

Comment: for now I just added couple more windows specific tasks in the rake file. Working fine now.                                          `desc "Deploys to S3 from Windows"
task :wdeploy do
  system 'python C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\s3cmd sync --delete-removed --acl-public _site/ s3://mysite.com --verbose'
end`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case: we built a free open-source analog [s3cmdwin](https://github.com/jitbit/s3cmdwin) - a very (very!) simple command line tool to upload a file to s3 or list existing files in a bucket, based on Amazon's nuget-published SDK.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the contributors.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in a s3cmd.bat (or s3cmd.cmd) in a place somewhere in your path:

```
python C:\Python27\Scripts\s3cmd %*
```

And you should be able to cast commands like `s3cmd sync --etc...`!